# Apache Nifi Nightmare On Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi

I’m having a real nightmare with the initial steps of setup with Apache Nifi on Kubernetes. I have installed via this helm link https://github.com/cetic/helm-nifi/issues. Once installed I read through the documentation that on startup Nifi logs (app-log) temporary username and password. I see  and  in the logs but neither work when try to log in via the port forward ( web ui) the error returns

The supplied username and password are not valid.

I found an article explaining to run the following to reset the username and password so I logged into the main pod and run./nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials admin admin1234567.
This seems to work as expected and I can see it updated the login-identity-providers.xml (username is what I set and password hash has changed ) I try access again and same error .when I restart the Nifi service ( pod restart ) all my changes are lost so back to square one ( and no new login credsmentioned in the app log ) . Anyone managed to crack this on Kubernetes ?

Comment: It's normal that after restart docker resets all to original state. If you want file/folder to be preserved between restarts - mount it to external storage.